# propositional logic, does An have to be a numerical expression/equation?

Tags: logic

So if the $propositional$ $symbols$ are $A_{n}$ for all $n$ in the natural numbers, does that mean that our statements are not in terms of sentences with true/false values (which can be represented by the likes of p, q), but instead are actually numerical expression? (like the false statement $n=n+1$, for instance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *propositional logic* we need an infinite set of *propositional symbols*.

It is useful in some theorem to have an "enumeration" of them; thus, we usually use : $A_n, n \ge 0$, or : $p_i, i \ge 0$. The choice is immaterial.

We can use a very limited vocabulary, made of only two symbols : $p$ and $'$, and build all the needed *propositional symbols* as follows :

> $p', p'', p''', \ldots$.

Having said that, *propositional logic* is a "model" used to formalize some basic rules of logic.

If you want to apply it to some mathematical or "general" contexts, you have to replace the propositional letters with *sentences* [i.e. expressions "with true/false values"] of the language you are working with.

If we consider *arithmetic* language, we con consider the *true* sentences :

> $1 \ne 0$ or $\forall n(0 \ne n+1)$

or the *false* one :

> $\forall n(n=n+1)$.

In this way, form the *tautology* (i.e. a formula of *propositional logic* which is true in every interpretation) :

> $p \lor \lnot p$

we can derive (by substitution of a sentence in place of the propositional symbol $p$) an infinite number of true sentences.

In particular, if we consider the examples above regarding the language of arithmetic, we have that the sentence :

> > $\forall n(n=n+1) \lor \lnot \forall n(n=n+1)$

is an *instance* of the above tautology. Thus it is a true sentence of arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

A proposition is any sentence that can only be true or false.
for example:
 1. $A_n=[n \mbox{ is even}]$
 2. $A_n=[p_1 \land p_2 \land p_3 \land \dots \land p_n]$ where $p_k \mbox{ is } T \mbox{ or } F$
 3. $A_n=[n \mbox{ is prime}]$
this three propositions depend on $n$ but they can only have one thruth value.
in propositional logic a symbol is either a logic operator (eg. $\land$,$\lor$,$\lnot$) or a proposition.

Answer (score 1):

No. We can make any scribble and call it a symbol. It is just more convenient sometimes to order all the symbols numerically: eg $A_1, A_2, A_3$ instead of $A, B, C$...

Answer (score 1):

In listing the propositions as $A_1, A_2, A_3, \ldots, A_n, \ldots$, we are merely saying that there is a list of them, and $n$ is an *index* to that list. We are not saying that they are functions (or expressions, or whatever) that actually depend on $n$. Similarly, I could define the sequence $A_n$ as being the nth word in the Oxford English Dictionary, such that $A_1=\mbox{"a"}$, $A_2=\mbox{"ab"}$, $A_{5562}=\mbox{"graph"}$ (perhaps), and so forth.